# How to override Date.today when running rails tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have some tests that were failing on specific dates, because someone wrote them to use `Date.today`. I want to reproduce the failures on previous select dates.

Is there a way to run rake test with an ENV variable that will override the system clock? So that calls to `Date.today`, `Time.now`, and `1.day.ago` and `1.day.from_now` will use the date I set?

Like, for example:

```
> DATE_TODAY='2017-01-04' rake test
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **testing** you can use [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem.
It offers you two useful methods `Timecop.freeze` and `Timecop.travel`.

For example, you can use `freeze` to statically set time in **before hooks**:

```
describe 'your tests' do
  before do
    Timecop.freeze(Time.new(2017, 1, 4))
  end

  after do
    Timecop.return
  end

  it 'should do something' do
    sleep(10)
    Time.now # => 2017-01-04 00:00:00
  end
end
```

Or in a **block**:

```
Timecop.freeze(Time.now - 3.months) do
  assert product.expired?
end
```

While with the `travel` method, you change the starting moment, but **time is still passing by**.

```
Timecop.travel(Time.new(2017, 1, 4))
sleep(10)
Time.now # => 2017-01-04 00:00:10
```

Comment: If you are using Rails `v4.1+`, then there are now built-in [`TimeHelpers`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html) - which *probably* (at least, for simple scenarios like this) makes incorporating a third party library such as a`TimeCop` unnecessary.

Comment: @TomLord post an answer please. I use it and its awesome.

Comment: @TomLord note that DateTime.now wasn't supported for time_travel before Rails 5.

Comment: I believe this answer (and Timecop itself) are pretty much outdated now that Rails has `TimeHelpers`. I'd recommend [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41469122/199712) instead.

Answer (score 7):

As of Rails 4.1 you can do

```
travel_to Time.new(2004, 11, 24, 01, 04, 44)
```

The full API docs are here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html

Comment: Thanks, this was very nice to know, although in my case I was using Rails 4